# Нижнее подчёркивание и -s, что обозначают?

Tags: perl

Вот такой код, что за цифры он выдаёт, какой в них смысл? (perl v5.20.2)

```
perl -E 'say -s _'
871
```

**Дополнено**

Как удалось разузнать `_` — это файловый дескриптор, который хранит информацию по предыдущему результату запроса stat к некоему файлу, т.е:

```
print -s "file.txt";
print -r "file.txt";
```

тоже самое, что и:

```
print -s "file.txt";
print -r _;
```

Ну а оператор `-s` возвращает информацию по размеру файла в байтах.

Остаётся открытым вопрос, информация о каком файле хранится в `_` по умолчанию? Вот, что удалось узнать по данному дескриптору:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

print "Filesize: ". -s _,"\n".
      "Is plain file: " . -f _,"\n".
      "Is readable: ".(-r _ || 0),"\n".
      "Is writable: ".(-w _ || 0),"\n".
      "Is owned: ".(-o _ || 0), "\n".
      "Is opened to a tty: ".(-t _ || 0), "\n".
      "Is setuid bit: ".(-u _ || 0), "\n".
      "Is setgid bit: ".(-g _ || 0), "\n".
      "Is sticky bit: ".(-k _ || 0), "\n".
      "Is binary: ".(-B _ || 0), "\n".
      "Last modification time (days ago): ".-M _, "\n".
      "Last access time (days ago): ".-A _, "\n";
```

Выдаёт:

```
Filesize: 871
Is plain file: 1
Is readable: 1
Is writable: 0
Is owned: 0
Is opened to a tty: 0
Is setuid bit: 0
Is setgid bit: 0
Is sticky bit: 0
Is binary: 0
Last modification time (days ago): 610.295925925926
Last access time (days ago): 0.121157407407407
```

Comment: "Нижнее подчёркивание" -- а бывает "верхнее *под*чёркивание"???

Comment: Вообще подчеркивание берет их специального кеша данные по последнему проверяемому файлу. например `-f "aaa.txt" && -s _` проверит что файл "aaa.txt" есть и даст его размер. При этом это быстрее, чем `-f "aaa.txt" && -s "aaa.txt"`, потому что атрибуты файла уже запомнены после -f. Но в вашем случае я не понимаю, размер какого файла он выводит. И у меня ваша команда выдает пустую строку, проверял на двух машинах с разными версиями perl

Comment: @Mike да, уже разобрался, что это наподобие $_ но для файловых дескрипторов, во время получения stat информации. Другое дело, что непонятно, что это за файл открыт в данном случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> информация о каком файле хранится в _ по умолчанию?

Вы же сами на этот вопрос ответили уже:

> `_` — это файловый дескриптор, который хранит информацию по предыдущему результату запроса stat к некоему файлу

В связи с тем, что вы в ваших программах подключаете модуля, они могут делать обращения к файлам. Вы как раз результат этого обращения и видите.

Это работает по аналогии с [`$!` переменной](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)

---

Комманда `stat` может венуть inode для текущего файла. Потом по этому inode можно найти сам файл:

```
find -inum $(perl -e 'print +(stat(_))[1]')
```

Но в связи с тем, что до вызова `stat` с именем файла, в `_` будет мусор, то комманда выше может завершится с ошибкой.

Comment: `perl -E 'say -s _'` выдасти 871, хотя здесь нет подключения модулей. Вопрос о том, что за файл в _ открыт...

Comment: @edem: `-E: behaves just like -e, except that it implicitly enables all optional features`. Как минимум подключаются все модули фич, а это в свою очередь и use strict, и use warnings

Comment: Ну конечно, только `perl -e 'print -s _'` выдаёт аналогичный результат.

Comment: @edem: Я вот у себя проверил: 5.26.1, 5.24.0, 5.18.4, 5.6.2 - везде выдаёт `undef`. Работает оно именно так, как я указал выше в ответе. У вас какая сборка перла?

Comment: В вопросе есть вся инфа по этому. Версия 5.20.2. То, что выдавать должен undef, это понятно. Вопрос в том, что за файл там в 871 и как это узнать?

Comment: @edem: Добавил комманду для получения имени файла